# GCC floating point error if optimizer enabled

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

I'm looking for a workaround for a GCC optimizer bug.  The bug was in v4.5 and is still present in v5.3.0, alas.  Here's the problem C code snippet (part of a printf-like func):

```
d *= factor;
if ((d > 0) && (d < 1))     /* 9.9e-1 instead of 0.99e0 */
{
    exp--;
    d *= 10;
}
else if (!sci && (d >= 10)) /* 1e0 instead of 10e-1 */
{
    exp++;
    d /= 10;
}
```

With -O1 or -O2, this code does not produce correct results.  But, if I insert a function call like srand() or similar after "d *= factor" and before the "if", then the code compiles right and produces the expected result.

I've tried inserting other things there in place of the function call, to try to nudge the compiler into a different state w/o the bug, but so far only a function call seems to work.

Which leads to the question: any better suggestions for a workaround?

I haven't been able to produce a small test case for this or I would have reported it as a GCC bug.  If I extract the above code segment from the larger function it works fine; it only fails when part of the long and complicated overall function.

Here is another snippet very similar in form to the first one, which also has the same problem.  If I insert a function call between the assignment and the if, the problem goes away.

```
gl = gc->mgr * pat_round(l / gc->mgr);
dl = l - gl; 
if (((dl * gc->last_dl) < 0) &&
        ((gl == gc->last_gl) || ((gl * gc->last_gl) < 0)))
{
    ...
}
```

These are doubles being compared in both cases.

Here is the assembler for the hacked version of the first snippet, with a srand(0) call stuck in to make it work (I marked the instructions which change with a '*'):

```
.L461:
    fldl    (%esp)
    fmull   24(%esp)
    fstpl   (%esp)
    subl    $12, %esp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4252
    pushl   $0
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4256
    call    srand
    addl    $16, %esp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 4240
    fldz
    fldl    (%esp)
    fucomi  %st(1), %st
    fstp    %st(1)
    jbe     .L559
    fld1
    fucomip %st(1), %st
    jbe     .L560
    decl    %ebp
    fmuls   .LC2
    fstpl   (%esp)
    jmp     .L457
```

and here is the same thing with the srand(0) removed-- this is the non-working version:

```
.L461:
    fldl    (%esp)
    fmull   24(%esp)
    fstl    (%esp)
    fldz
    fxch    %st(1)
    fucomi  %st(1), %st
    fstp    %st(1)
    jbe     .L559
    fld1
    fucomip %st(1), %st
    jbe     .L560
    decl    %ebp
    fmuls   .LC2
    fstpl   (%esp)
    jmp     .L457
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the help info. You'll get much better results if your example compiles and runs.

Comment: What are the data types of the variables involved? By the way, are you *sure* you've hit a compiler bug? Especially if the problem goes away when you try to observe it, this sounds more like undefined behavior. What have you tried to verify that your code is correct? It is hard to reason about this with an incomplete example.

Comment: The question is unanswerable; all you will get is a series of "try this" comments.  Unless you can at least describe the expected and actual behaviour, and indicate the data types, I am not sure how we can help.  Compiler bug is possible but amongst the least likely explanations.  A dump of the assembly code related to this source might help. If it is an optimiser bug, have you tried declaring `d` volatile?

Comment: Gene, yes I know a small standalone example is best but I can't provide it.asm("nop") doesn't do it.  Yes, it's a compiler bug.  The code works fine and produces correct results when compiled without optimization.  With -O1 or -O2 it fails, apparently because the if/else branches don't execute.

Comment: Disassemble and post the disassembly with and without the call to srand(). Just post the part of the disassembly that corresponds to the posted code. That'll be a definitive way to determine if a compiler error is present. It may also suggest a work around.

Comment: I'd be very careful about asserting that something is a compiler bug unless you can demonstrate an SSCCE that doesn't trace to an error in the code. For all we know, it's either undefined behavior or some sort of fast floating-point optimization. Differences between the optimizations levels does not imply a compiler bug. It can be undefined behavior among other things.

Comment: Where is your bug-report there: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=optimizer ? `if(notReported){` you use a fine product that was provided for free to you, proclaim a bug where there is none with 999‰ certainity, and then ask for free workarounds somewhere else without even giving an SSCCE?  `}`

Comment: I highly recommend this paper: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/281429/filename/floating-point-article.pdf, especially section 3. It goes into some detail on the perils of the x87 80-bit representation (excess precision, double rounding, register spill, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

A few details would help here, such as a brief description of the unexpected behaviour. Lacking that, we are forced to fall back on telepathy and crystal balls, which are notoriously unreliable.

According to my ouija board, your problem is that at the termination of that snippet, you expect `d` to be in the half closed range [1, 10). But it turns out that `d` is actually 10. When you interpose a function call, however, `d` mysteriously changes to the correct value.

This can happen, and it is not an optimiser bug. Although `double` has a fixed precision, and is nominally used throughout the computation, the compiler is permitted to perform intermediate computations in a higher precision, which can result in variables appearing to be of a more precise type at various points in their lifetime.

Now, let's telepathically ascertain that the product `d * factor` is just slightly less than 1, if computed precisely. It is so close to 1, in fact, that if it were rounded to 53 bits of precision, it would round to 1.0. But it happens to have 64 bits of precision at that point, so it's a tiny bit less. Now we multiply by 10, (because it was less than 1, as per the test) and round the result to 53 bits because we no longer keep the value in a register. The rounded value will turn out to be 10, contravening the expectation (except the expectation of the spirit world, who knew it all along.)

Interposing a function call will force the compiler to save the value in the floating point register, so it will be corrected to 53 bits before the comparison with 1, and thus will compare equal, not less.

Of course, all of the above is just a flight of fantasy since it has no basis whatsoever in reported evidence. If it turns out to have any resemblance with reality, that will just be one of those inexplicable coincidences.

In that hypothetical case, forcing the compiler to use SSE for floating point arithmetic would avoid the excess precision computations, since SSE registers are only 64 bits. Alternatively, you can tell GCC to work harder to avoid 80-bit intermediates. See the `-mfpmath=sse` option, and also `-ffloat-store` and `-fexcess-precision=standard` (SSE is generally rhe best.)

Comment: Yes, I have run into this sort of problem before, too:  God I hate working with floating point.  Anyway, your explanation makes sense since this code is messing with corner cases and could likely run afoul of hidden precision variations, but the other bit of code with the same problem, while floating-point also, isn't dealing with any suspicious numbers

Comment: @ian: i see you edited the question, coming perilously close to actually describing the problem. The assembly code is full of x87 opcodes, which lends credibility to my ouija board. Its suggestion is that you tell gcc to use SSE registers, which don't have the extra precision bits. See -msse and friends.

Comment: @ian.macky: Don't you think that proclaiming an optimizer bug in a mature and well-established C++ compiler that is available at no charge, when you have no clue about the compiler's floating point implementation, nor about floating point in general, is a story full of hybris and ignorance?

Comment: @phresnel: But isn't hubris one of the [three great virtues](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris) of a programmer?!

Comment: -mfpmath=sse didn't make any difference, but -ffloat-store and -fexcess-precision=standard both did... but I don't want to compile the entire file that way just because of one problem statement.  Declaring the vars volatile also works.  Guess I will do that.

Comment: @ian.macky: -mfpmath=sse isn't enough if you are compiling on a 32-bit platform. There are lots of useful details in the GNU manual. Unless you're using really old hardware, you'll find that using SSE is faster as well as solving the excess precision problem, but of course it is up to you. (When I said "see the _X_ options", I meant that you should check them out in the manual. In fact, the GCC manual contains a discussion of this very issue, iirc under Disappointments.)